# Installing libcap package on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I couldn't install libcap package to use CAP_SYS_ADMIN on Raspberry Pi 3.

How can I install it? I couldn't understand installing step in some websites.

This is the version page of libcab

https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/linux-privs/libcap2/

How can I install one of them?

Comment: Why don't you use a package manager?

Comment: As i said , I'm new.How can i use ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I had the package from the first answer already installed, was using jpcap for java and installing this resolves the dependency issue i had

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

To install libcap use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2
```